# Objective C: App Crashes when setting up connection (during refresh)

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have a UItableView controller containing images. I also have a refresh button to re-retrieve the data from server in JSON format and populating the UITableView again.

However I am facing an issue whereby the app will crash sometimes when I click on the refresh button (erratic behaviour).

The screenshot of my crash is as follows

From here is seems like the error comes from synthesizing a property, and my assumption is that the error comes from trying to access the property aConnection
[image]

I checked the thread on the left hand panel and the following screenshot seems to indicate that the crash happened somewhere when I tried to set the aConnection again.
[image]

I am not sure if I posted enough information here, but any advise on how I can proceed will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this method.

```
- (void)getData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [ [ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];             
    NSString *urlGen = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myurlforjson"];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlGen);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlGen]; // Modify this to match your url.    
    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; // Pulls the URL   
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];   NSError *error = nil;
    // I am using specific JSON Libraries to parse json data
    NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
    if (dict)
    {
        self.storageDictionary = [dict objectForKey:@"JSONItemNAME"];
        [self parseNumberofStores:self.listData];                        
        [self.listData retain];     
    }
    [urlGen release];
    [jsonreturn release];
    [self.table reloadData];
    if ([self.listData count] <= 0 )
    {
        UIAlertView *al = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops !" message:@"Sorry ! No Items Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [al show];
        [al release];
        //[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    if ([activity isAnimating]) {
        [activity stopAnimating];
    }
    [tableview reloadData];
    [pool release]; 
}
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.

You might need to call this method from some click or load event try using this

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(getData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```